# Prevent PHP file upload from shared network

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, bootstrap-4

I have a file upload in PHP to a customer but because of their network is slow does it work bad when they upload from their network (it works well if they upload from ex their computer desktop).

Can I prevent the user to select files from their network, and only allow from their own computer?

I had a thought to only allow file path starting with network path, `\\` or `//` in the function `fileSelected()`. But due to security in new browsers, it is not possible to read the users upload path with JavaScript/jQuery because it is replaced with "fakepath".

My script is a standard file upload in PHP.

```
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" name="fileToUpload" accept=".zip" required>
<span id="selected-file" class="custom-file-label" for="fileToUpload">Choose file</span>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
Please select a file.
</div>
</div>

function fileSelected() {
//Calculate size
}

function uploadFile(fd) {
    fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "src/fileUpload.php");
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

fileUpload.php

```
<?php
//$fileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileName = $_SESSION['fileName'];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../uploads/$fileName")
?>
```

Comment: let me get this straight: "upload from the network" does that mean that they choose a file on the internet or on a file share (cifs/smb) or something else?

Comment: local file share. In Windows you can select Network and get files from another computer in your network, this gives a address like \\SERVER01\USER\DOCS\LETTER.TXT but I only want to allow to uplod from ex C:\USER\DOCS\LETTER.TXT

Comment: Maybe another approach would help: if you implement an ajax file upload feature, and do something like checking the filesize before uploading, with a timeout. if the timeout is triggered, then you abort the upload

Comment: maybe something like this ajax uploader could give you some inspiration: https://github.com/danielm/uploader